# Is WAP still a relevant protocol stack?

Tags: wireless, protocol-theory, transport-protocol

Please overlook any oversight. I couldn't find much recent material on the internet, and just had a networks course this semester.

The wiki page mentions that as of 2013, it's usage has largely been absent. 
But I found a stack exchange thread dated 2011 that the WAP 2.0 is still in use.

As of 2015, with the current crop of smartphones and high-speed 3g/4g services provided by the operators, is WAP still supported or used? And what version(s) exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WAP is still used. I don't know which version it is. It's usage is really small. In our network it generates 200-300 times smaller traffic compared to the other mobile Internet traffic (http, ftp and other).

I don't know why it is still used. Maybe some companies have old devices which are using this protocol - like taxi, tracking, cash terminals, or other similar devices (this is just an example - I'm not sure if these devices actually use WAP).

Answer (score 1):

Yes and No.

Definitely still being use even though it is on a decreasing trend..

Adding on to @goelakash, reason being used are mostly due to old devices and how much / well the IT OR the business view the IT.

For most businesses, if there are no incident, they will not invest in IT no matter how much we warn them.

As for no, it is because network devices are being upgraded over time for whatever reasons, be it wear and tear or simply because somebody kick the network device (it happens). Thus, IT personnel will take this chance to upgrade to a more relevant device .